# how to display negative values in red on Excel using xlwings?

Tags: python, format, xlwings, negative-number

I imported my python dataframe to Excel using xlwings, I am wondering how to show my negative numbers in red by xlwings.

please advise.

To be a little more precise; I do some analysis in python then extract the result(1row) into Excel, add up it to that previous days result rows.

Answer (score 0):

What i'd do is take a slice out of the dataframe, of the column where you want to turn the negative columns red. This example is considering that you want to paste the third column of the dataframe into the C column in excel i.e.

```
slice = df.iloc[:,2] 
for i in range(0,len(slice)-1):
   excellocation = "C" + str(i)
   if slice[i] < 0:
       ws.range(excellocation).value = slice[i]
       ws.range(excellocation).api.Font.Color = rgb_to_int((255,0,0))
   else:
       ws.range(excellocation).value = slice[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply the below code:

```
range.api.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).